# Rails. Undefined method `remove_product' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

App models:
**Cart** `has_many :line_items`
**Product** `has_many :line_items`
**LineItem** `belongs_to :cart`, `belongs_to :product`

If the same product being added in the cart multiple times, I count that number in **cart.rb**:

```
  def add_product(product)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product.id)
    end
    current_item
  end
```

Now I want to give user ability to increase / decrease that number. Increasing going well:

**line_items_controller.rb**:

```
  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to store_index_url }
        format.js   { @highlited_item = @line_item }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**line_item.html.erb**:

```
<td><%= link_to "+", line_items_path(product_id: line_item.product), method: :post, remote: true %></td>
```

But decreasing doesn't go so well. My plan is:

**cart.rb** (not sure how this would work, since here that error of undefined method add_product fires up):

```
  def remove_product(product)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id)
    if current_item.quantity > 1
      current_item.quantity -= 1
    elsif current_item.quantity = 1
      current_item.destroy
    end
    current_item unless current_item.nil
  end
```

**line_items_controller.rb**:

```
  def decrease
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.remove_product(product)
  end
```

Full **line_items_controller.rb**:

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
      include CurrentCart
      before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
      before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      def index
        @line_items = LineItem.all
      end

      def show
      end

      def new
        @line_item = LineItem.new
      end

      def edit
      end

      def create
        product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        @line_item = @cart.add_product(product)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @line_item.save
            format.html { redirect_to store_index_url }
            format.js   { @highlited_item = @line_item }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @line_item.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to line_items_url, notice: 'Line item was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end


      private
        def set_line_item
          @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
        end

        def line_item_params
          params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id)
        end
    end
```

Why I get that undefined method `remove_product` in `decrease` action?

Many thanks!

Comment: `@cart` is not defined. If you set it up with the `before_action`, then you need to `decrease` method for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Undefined method 'remove_product' for nil:NilClass

The error is because `@cart` is ***not*** defined in the `decrease` method. As you have set `@cart` with `before_action`, you need to tweak it as below so that `@cart` will be available for `decrease` method as well.

```
before_action :set_cart, only: [:create, :decrease]
```

This will solve your problem.

> But why the add_product method works?

The problem is not with `remove_product` or `add_product`, it is with `@cart` ***not being defined*** in `decrease` method. As the `@cart` is ***available*** for `create` method, it ***didn't triggered the error***.

Comment: @J.D. I updated my answer to provide an explanation for your comment under the question. Please do check.

Comment: I figured it out the same moment u posted answer :D Thanks!